# Terminate a while loop using `getchar()`

Tags: c, getchar

For my homework assignment, I need to implement Horners Algorithm for converting between bases.

I have been told to use `getchar()` for this assignment. But I am having a problem where when I hit enter, the program doesn't terminate and just takes in more chars.

Example:

```
bryce> ./pa1
Enter the fromRadix:16

Enter the toRadix:2
abc
abc
^C
bryce>
```

Code:

```
int readRadixA(int radixA)
{
    char myChar = getchar(); 
    int result = 0; 
    int run = 0; 

    while(myChar != EOF)
    {
        if(myChar == "\n")
            break;

        Horners();

        myChar = getchar(); 
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am not asking for help implementing Horners; I am asking for help to terminate the `getchar()` correctly.

Comment: I had to do ^C to terminate the program.

Comment: Have you tried `^D`, the EOF character of Unix shells? :) On Windows, `^Z` might work in this role. You could also consider finishing your program on two `\n`s in a row (that is, typing an empty line).

Comment: `getchar` returns an **int**. Not a char, an **int**. `myChar` **needs  to be an `int`**.

Comment: I'm doing this via a Mac SSHed into a linux box.

Comment: thank you @9000 , your reply helped me. i use Debian 10 on virtualbox 6.1.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> if(myChar=="\n")
>            ^  ^
> ```

You're comparing `myChar` wrong. Try this instead:

```
if(myChar == '\n') 
             ^  ^
```

A second problem is that `getchar` returns `int`, not `char`. Maybe you can rewrite it like this:

```
int myChar;
while((myChar = getchar()) != EOF && myChar != '\n')
{
    /* Your stuff. */
}
```

#### EDIT

In light of comments, I think some stdio operation before that `while` is leaving a `\n` in the buffer.

Instead of `scanf("%d", &radix)` try:

```
scanf("%d ", &radix);
         ^
```

That space will make `scanf` eat the remaining blanks (including the newline).

Comment: I try that, and my program immediately terminates after I enter my commands for enter radix from and to. Meaning I cannot input into the get char.

Comment: @Snow_Mac What did you enter ? What did you expect ?

Comment: Program prompts me: Enter the fromRadix:, then I type 16, then it prompts:Enter the toRadix:, then I type 2. After this is where my method gets called with getchar(); which I should be able to type abc.

Comment: I'm doing this via a Mac SSHed into a linux box.

Comment: @Snow_Mac: I'd bet that the code that reads in `fromRadix` and `toReadix` (`scanf()` I bet) is leaving the '\n' in the buffer, so it's the first character returned by `getchar()` when `readRadixA()` is executed.

Comment: @Snow_Mac I completely agree with Michael Burr, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return type of `getchar()`. Yes, it's an *int*. That's because `EOF` must have a value that can be distinguished from a valid character. `myChar` must actually be made to be `int`.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, to end the standard input, you have to type  `Ctrl-D`. The kernel and [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) layers makes that an end-of-file mark or condition. Then `getchar` gives `EOF` (which is *not* a valid `char`, for example on systems where `char` are unsigned bytes between 0 and 255, `EOF` could be -1).

Notice that [feof(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html) is valid only *after* a read operation (e.g. `getchar`, `fgets`, etc...) so coding `while(feof(stdin))` is generally wrong (contrarily to what I wrote in  the previous version of this answer). You'll better test that `getchar` is returning `EOF` so your `myChar` should be an `int` (not a `char`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
int readRadixA(int radixA)
{
    char myChar;
    int result = 0; 
    int run = 0; 

    do
    {
        myChar = getchar(); 
        // implement horners here
    }while(myChar != 13);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What's up with the `13`? Don't you know it's unlucky?

Comment: 13 is the ascii value of `ENTER` key

Comment: But it is not immediately obvious to those who have not had their ASCII tables memorized. And it's a carriage return, BTW, not the "`Enter`" key. If you insist on not using `'\r'`, at least use the conventional `0x0D`. But then again, a linefeed, `10`, `0x0A`, or **`'\n'`** is much more standard than a carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code I think you are leaving a '\n' in the input keyboard buffer after the toRadix.

And their is one more thing that

```
 getchar()
```

reads all the characters in one go till a '\n' is received.

And there is one more mistake you have committed by comparing a

```
   char to a pointer e.g  mychar=="\n"
```

further information about your implementation of toRadix can be really helpful to answer your question